# How to find the zip code corresponding to a latitude / longitude

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude, zipcode

How to find the zip code corresponding to a latitude / longitude?

What tools are available to fetch this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google provides Geocoding/Reverse geocoding API which allow you to get address information from lat/lng.

i.e.)
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false

In the result, you can find the postal code like this:
[image]

More detail, please read the official document.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: is this  api is fully free to use and has no any usage limites.?